# Getting Error : "file is being used by another process c#"

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I am attempting to delete a file that exists on my harddrive but getting an exception that the file cannot be deleted because 'file is being used by another process'.

```
public void btnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(File.Exists("C:\\\test.txt"))
    {
        File.Delete("C:\\\test.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Why I am not able to delete the file?.. It is opened nowhere..!!

Comment: You probably left an open (non-disposed) stream in your own code.

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). Use the Find menu -> Find handle or DLL string. Type in the name of the file and hit Search. It'll tell you which process has it open.

Comment: Yes, due to File.Create the file was opening and as the file was not closed any update in the file was denied. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete a file that is locked by another process. This is prevented by the OS. Here is described a way to do it anyway: [ForceDel - Delete locked files](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/files/fileio/article.php/c1287/Deleting-Locked-Files.htm). Quoted from there about the procedure:

```
Note: 1. SE_DEBUG privilege must be enabled. 
      2. The function works with every kind of HANDLE
      3. It will bother the remote process :)
      4. The handles will be invalid after you closed 
         them remotely
```

So it can even crash the other process. It works by

- Opening the other process
- Creating a thread in the other process which consists of/executes CloseHandle()
- Waits for the thread to complete
- Closes the thread and process handles
- Then deletes the file

You'd have to translate this C code to C# using `P/Invoke interop`, [here is some code demonstrating P/Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494062/1305969), but with different functions.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the file is not open whether by yourself or a file reader object.

Try this logic to make sure the same thread that you have open for checking to see if it exists isn't keeping a reference to the file allowing you to not

```
public void btnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var exists = false;
    if(File.Exists("C:\\\test.txt")) 
    {
        exists = true;
    } 

    if(exists)
    {
        File.Delete("C:\\\test.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the file is opened as I am not using File reader object anywhere, I am just checking whether the file exists.. If yes, delete the file.

Comment: Why use two if blocks instead of just just sticking the File.Delete("C:\\\test.txt") where the 'exists = true' line is? Seems like there is no need to do two checks on the same thing when nothing is happening in between.

Comment: Sometimes if you kill process that has an open handle to a file, system keeps that handle to the next reboot, that's why no one will be able to open file with write access or delete it.